# convert special character to html in PHP

Tags: php, html, character

I'm trying to convert special characters into html to have them display properly.

Anybody can help me? how can I apply htmlspecialchars() at below php line

```
<?php echo $xcityid>0?$upperCase=strtoupper(str_replace("-", " ", "$xcityname")):"testing"; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change your syntax as below:

```
<?php echo ($xcityid > 0) ? htmlspecialchars(strtoupper(str_replace("-", " ", "$xcityname"))) : "testing"; ?>
```

Comment: thanks for both of you but it's not returning what I desire. For example a word "Golléré" but it's printing "Goll r". Do I need to mention UTF-8 something in the above syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?= ($xcityid > 0) ? htmlspecialchars(strtoupper(str_replace("-", " ", $xcityname))) : "testing"; ?>
```

Comment: thanks for both of you but it's not returning what I desire. For example a word "Golléré" but it's printing "Goll r". Do I need to mention UTF-8 something in the above syntax?

Comment: @malic: You may need to use `setlocale` to set the locale you're running in, e.g. `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "fr_FR")` for French. That depends on the locale being installed, mind you.

Comment: oh I think i need to re-phrase my question

Actually those are non-english characters in the script it's fetching from mysql fine but when I added some html and then tried to fetch the same thing I can't get let's say "Golléré" is displaying in the html "Goll r".

But in the script at the same page it's fetching Golléré properly. 

Any idea?

Comment: @malic: Try `htmlentities` instead. `htmlspecialchars` will only convert a small, restricted range of characters (only &, ", ', < and >). `htmlentities` converts **everything**. You'll also need to tell it what encoding you're using. Try this as a test: `htmlentities("Golléré")`. If you get `Goll&Atilde;&copy;r&Atilde;&copy;`, then it's not using the right encoding. For me, `htmlentities("Golléré", ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8")` returns `Goll&eacute;r&eacute;`, which is right!